# How to use object to optimise the query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to optimise this query by creating a object. But I don't know how to do, and I don't understand why using object can optimise this query in this case.

I have a WINE table: (I cannot change the data type in this case)

```
CREATE TABLE wine (
    vintage    NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    wine_no    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    vid        CHAR(08) NOT NULL,
    cid        CHAR(06) NOT NULL,
    pctalc     NUMBER(4, 2),
    price      NUMBER(6, 2),
    grade      CHAR(01) NOT NULL,
    wname      CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    comments   CHAR(200) NOT NULL
);
```

I tried to create object by following this link:https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm
but I don't know it is the right track and how to implement

This is the query I need to optimise:

```
SELECT w.wname,
       SUM(w.price) sold_total
  FROM wine w
 GROUP BY w.wname;
```

this is my explain plan, and would like to run it faster

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4045097665

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          |     1 |    45 |    32   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY     |          |     1 |    45 |    32   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| WINE |  1500 | 67500 |    31   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

9 rows selected.
```

Any thoughts?
Do I have any way to optimise this query (not change data type)?
Could someone help me and teach me, thank a lot!

Comment: Why do you believe that creating an object type would allow you to optimize this query?  If the goal is to optimize the query, I cannot imagine a path that would involve creating an object type.  How many rows in the table, how fast does the query run now, how fast do you need it to run, what is the query plan, etc.?  My guess is that fixing the data model to use `varchar2` rather than `char` is the easiest optimization.  Potentially, a materialized view could be used to preaggregate the data but that will have implications for inserts, updates, and deletes.

Comment: @JustinCave i'm happy we're on the same page, even at the exact same time :)

Comment: I asked for using object because it said it is the tips for optimise this query in my homework, but I already don't have any ideas how object can optimise this query. Also, I cannot change the data model o varchar2 in this case so is any other directions for me to optimise this query? Thank a lot everyone!

Comment: Unrelated, but: do not use the `CHAR` type. It as absolutely not advantage but several obnoxious disadvantages.

Comment: an index on `(wname, price)` might help, so that the full table access is replaced with a (slightly) more efficient index full scan

Comment: @Polly - you might need to go back to whoever gave you the tip for clarification. They might have meant a wider interpretation of 'object' than you picked up; an index is still an object in one sense (it's in `all_objects` for a start), while you are trying to create an object *type*. So this might all be a bit of a misunderstanding, and we can't see exactly what you were told, of course.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how can i use index for wname and price, if my wname is null (in my assignment this column data is null so i can't change it). Because in my understanding, index cannot be null value.

Comment: @AlexPoole I agreed you that I might misunderstanding the meaning of "object" from my lecture's tips. Do you have any ideas to optimise this query in any way (but not in change char type). Thanks

Comment: @Polly: `wname` is defined as `NOT NULL` so it can't contain null values - but why don't you simply create the index and check the execution plan?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I created index but the execution plan is same as above....don't know why! So i really no ideas how can optimise this query :( For the wname, is like all value is = ' ' (empty but not null).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is the query I need to optimise:
>
> ```
> SELECT w.wname,
>        SUM(w.price) sold_total
>   FROM wine w
>  GROUP BY w.wname;
> ```

How do you expect Oracle to tell you the total price of every single distinct value for `WNAME` without reading every row in the table and adding everything up?

Answer: it's can't.  It's a great database, but it's not magic.

Now, what you *can* do is give Oracle something *else* to read instead to get the answer... something smaller than the whole table.

#### Option 1 - Covering Index

The easy way to do this is to make a so-called "covering" index on the table.  A "covering" index is one that contains all of the columns that you use in your query, so that Oracle can use the index instead of the table.  E.g.,

```
CREATE INDEX wine_sum_n1 ON wine (wname, price);
```

However, in your case, your table rows are not very wide.  So, a covering index won't be that much smaller than the actual table.  It *would* help though and it is a very easy approach.

#### Option 2 - Materialized View with `ON QUERY COMPUTATION`

Another way to give Oracle a smaller thing to read is to pre-compute all the sums in a materialized view.  This is always problematic, because any DML changes to your table will cause the materialized view to become stale and you'll lose the performance benefits unless and until something refreshes it.

(Oracle has an `ON COMMIT REFRESH` option that avoids this problem, but that has several dangers and limitations.  I avoid it for having been burned in the past, but it's still worth reading up on).

Oracle 12.2 introduced a really cool option for materialized views called `ON QUERY COMPUTATION`.  This feature allows Oracle to still use materialized views, even if they are stale, by joining in data from the materialized view log.  It could be a good option for you, so I'll give a full example, below.

```
-- Setup
DROP TABLE wine;
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW wine_name_sum_mv;

CREATE TABLE wine (
    vintage    NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    wine_no    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    vid        CHAR(08) NOT NULL,
    cid        CHAR(06) NOT NULL,
    pctalc     NUMBER(4, 2),
    price      NUMBER(6, 2),
    grade      CHAR(01) NOT NULL,
    wname      CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    comments   CHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO wine 
  SELECT mod(rownum,10000) vintage,
         rownum wine_No,
         'xxxxxxxx' vid,
         'yyyyyy' cid,
         0 pctalc,
         50 price,
         'z' grade,
         'WINE #' || mod(rownum,100) wname,
         'made up data for wine' comments
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 100000;

COMMIT;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON wine
  WITH ROWID
  (wname, price)
  INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW wine_name_sum_mv
  REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
  ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
  ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION
AS
  SELECT w.wname,
         sum(w.price) sold_total
  FROM   wine w
  GROUP BY w.wname;

-- Verify material view is being used 
EXPLAIN PLAN 
  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'MMCP001' FOR
SELECT w.wname,
       SUM(w.price) sold_total
  FROM wine w
 GROUP BY w.wname;
```

> ```
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation                    | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                  |   100 |  4400 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |   1 |  MAT_VIEW REWRITE ACCESS FULL| WINE_NAME_SUM_MV |   100 |  4400 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

```
-- Run the INSERT again to change the underlying table
INSERT INTO wine 
SELECT mod(rownum,10000) vintage,
         rownum wine_No,
         'xxxxxxxx' vid,
         'yyyyyy' cid,
         0 pctalc,
         50 price,
         'z' grade,
         'WINE #' || mod(rownum,100) wname,
         'made up data for wine' comments
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 100000;

-- Verify whether material view is still being used 
EXPLAIN PLAN 
  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'MMCP001' FOR
SELECT w.wname,
       SUM(w.price) sold_total
  FROM wine w
 GROUP BY w.wname;
```

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation                         | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                          |   210 | 11550 |    30  (14)| 00:00:01 |
> |   1 |  VIEW                             |                          |   210 | 11550 |    30  (14)| 00:00:01 |
> |   2 |   UNION-ALL                       |                          |       |       |            |          |
> |*  3 |    VIEW                           | VW_FOJ_0                 |   100 |  5800 |    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |
> |*  4 |     HASH JOIN FULL OUTER          |                          |   100 |  2500 |    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |
> |   5 |      VIEW                         |                          |    10 |    80 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
> |   6 |       HASH GROUP BY               |                          |    10 |   640 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
> |*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL          | MLOG$_WINE               |  1000 | 64000 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |   8 |      VIEW                         |                          |   100 |  1700 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |   9 |       MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL        | WINE_NAME_SUM_MV         |   100 |  4400 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |* 10 |    VIEW                           | VW_FOJ_1                 |   100 |  7100 |    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |
> |* 11 |     HASH JOIN FULL OUTER          |                          |   100 |  3700 |    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |
> |  12 |      VIEW                         |                          |    10 |   300 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
> |  13 |       HASH GROUP BY               |                          |    10 |   640 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
> |* 14 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL          | MLOG$_WINE               |  1000 | 64000 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |  15 |      VIEW                         |                          |   100 |   700 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |  16 |       MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL        | WINE_NAME_SUM_MV         |   100 |  4400 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |  17 |    MERGE JOIN                     |                          |    10 |  1150 |    10  (20)| 00:00:01 |
> |  18 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| WINE_NAME_SUM_MV         |   100 |  4400 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |  19 |      INDEX FULL SCAN              | I_SNAP$_WINE_NAME_SUM_MV |   100 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |* 20 |     SORT JOIN                     |                          |    10 |   710 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |
> |  21 |      VIEW                         |                          |    10 |   710 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
> |  22 |       HASH GROUP BY               |                          |    10 |   640 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
> |* 23 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL          | MLOG$_WINE               |  1000 | 64000 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
> ---------------------------------------------------
>
>    3 - filter("AV$0"."OJ_MARK" IS NULL)
>    4 - access(SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("SNA$0"."WNAME")=SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("AV$0"."GB0"))
>    7 - filter("MAS$"."SNAPTIME$$">TO_DATE(' 2019-09-19 15:02:46', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
>   10 - filter("SNA$0"."SNA_OJ_MARK" IS NULL)
>   11 - access(SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("SNA$0"."WNAME")=SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("AV$0"."GB0"))
>   14 - filter("MAS$"."SNAPTIME$$">TO_DATE(' 2019-09-19 15:02:46', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
>   20 - access(SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("WNAME")=SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("AV$0"."GB0"))
>        filter(SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("WNAME")=SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("AV$0"."GB0"))
>   23 - filter("MAS$"."SNAPTIME$$">TO_DATE(' 2019-09-19 15:02:46', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
> ```

What this is showing is that Oracle still benefits a lot from the materialized view.  `ON QUERY COMPUTATION` seems like a really cool feature that gets us around many of the historical drawbacks of materialized views.  ***DISCLOSURE: I have not used it yet in Production code.  There may be pitfalls!***

Also, you still want to refresh your materialized views periodically.  The more data there is in the materialized view logs, the less `ON QUERY COMPUTATION` will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a PL/SQL Object type won't do anything to make your query faster.

Here's the plan for your query on a 19c database, no data, no stats, no indexes.

```
SQL_ID  703yw7hub9rq2, child number 0
-------------------------------------
SELECT w.wname,        SUM(w.price) sold_total   FROM wine w  GROUP BY 
w.wname

Plan hash value: 385313506

--------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | E-Rows |
--------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |        |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY     |      |      1 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| WINE |      1 |
--------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - Warning: basic plan statistics not available. These are only collected when:
       * hint 'gather_plan_statistics' is used for the statement or
       * parameter 'statistics_level' is set to 'ALL', at session or system level
```

For better help on your question, describe your performance problem. Show us the Execution Plan of your problematic SQL. Tell us about your STATS and any indexes you have.

General design feedback: I think what you want for your text columns, such as COMMENTS, is a VARCHAR2 - not a CHAR.

CHAR(8) will always take up 8 bytes (single byte data), even for strings of length 1, 2, 3..7. VARCHAR2() only stores the data as entered.

Comment: What if I cannot change the data type of wname, and if I want to optimise this query. Is there some better way to rewrite this query? I think about to use index to optimise it but i cannot use index for sum(). So it there are any way to optimise the aggregate function in this query? Thank you

Comment: did there are any way to optimise this query (but i cannot change the data type to char as it is default by my assignment requirement). My execution plan is same as yours but i tried index but it still have the same plan

Comment: You can use index for sum, function based indexes...but before we jump to indexes, read my answer again. We need you to better describe your performance problem, and that begins by sharing your actual execution plan.